# wpf equivalent of a Java EE syntax

Tags: c#, wpf, jakarta-ee, binding

I was just battling with a multi-window wpf application yesterday trying to get one binding to work on another window then I gave up and stuffed everything to one window.
But, I noticed no way of binding in the form, (in a regular JSP page);

```
<ui:textField ...text="#{SessionBean1.choosePlaceAndTimeForm.checkOutDate}".../>
```

If there was some way to have a Session object alive for the duration of the WPF app and if somehow I could bind to it from every window. My life would be easier. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this answer : [WPF Application using a global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161459/wpf-application-using-a-global-variable)

Either use the following Dictionary :

```
Application.Current.Properties
```

Which can be bound using (the key string is used without double quotes) :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Application.Current.Properties[MyPropertyKey]}" />
```

Or implement a static class :

```
public static class ConfigClass()
{
    public static int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you mean like `App.Current.Properties["NameOfProperty"] = 5;` to add a property. But current means the wpf window i'm setting the property from correct? What if i want to access that property from another wpf window. Will the current.properties have that property then? If i just bind 3 textboxes in 3 different windows to the same App.Current.Properties["NameOfProperty"] value will they work?

Comment: Yes as it is scoped to the Application object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the other thing that baffles me is why other people define a class and put the properties from the app obj to that class and use that class instead. Is it wrong to use the app class or something?

Comment: Depends on the context. Unit testing the App object is harder than unit testing a simple class.

Answer (score 0):

Use the App object.

You can put a resource in the ResourceDictionay of the App object and bind to it using a StaticResource binding. Or refer to it in the ViewModel of each window.