# C# WPF Passing data through multiple windows

Tags: c#, wpf, counter

i'm making a program where it will count each answer correct on each window and display the counter as a result. I've already figured out how to count the answer and display it on one page.

If anyone could point me in a direction on how to keep that count throughout multiple pages until the last one? Not asking for people to write me code out just don't have a lot of knowledge of carrying data through multiple windows.

Any help/links are appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT: I took your advice and assigned it to a static variable, this code updates the lblScore to 1, but when it navigates to the last page, it doesn't show that value in the label. Any advice?

```
        public partial class Question1 : Window
    {
        public Question1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }   

        private void Question1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblScore.Content = MyGlobals.Score.ToString();
        }

        private void btnNext1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox.Text == "1111")
            {
                MyGlobals.Score = MyGlobals.Score + 1;
                lblScore.Content = MyGlobals.Score.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show("Noice");
            }

            new Question3().Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}

public static class MyGlobals
{
    public static int Score;
}



/*Question3 Window*/



   namespace Maths_Quiz
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Question3.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Question3 : Window
    {
        public Question3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Question3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblScore.Content = MyGlobals.Score.ToString();
        }

        private void btnReturn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            new MainWindow().Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: bind to a static property

Comment: may be https://stackoverflow.com/q/1161459/3254405

Comment: Thanks for the replies, if you could have a look at my edit on the post would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Create an overload for the constructor and pass in the data as a parameter or store the data in properties settings

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i decided to bind it to a static variable. However, it isn't outputting the score in the final label. I've edited my post with my current code.